# Xamarin Android share apk install then crashed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to hybrid app development.

I have build my apk in my device.It's worked fine But when i sent the apk to another mobile, it get crashed.

Anyone know what is the problem.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new signing certificate that can use for signing Android applications.

save the apk file in some location.Then use that Apk . It will work like charm.

Refer this link
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/